# SQL prepared statement Invalid column Index?

Tags: sql

Having a lot of problems with the following code:

```
public  static ArrayList getKundeNrToOrder (String s_date, String e_date) throwsSQLException
{
    ResultSet rs    = null;

    Connection con  = null;
    int tal         = 0   ;

    try 
    {  
      Class.forName(DB.driver);
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB.URL, DB.ID, DB.PW);
      String query = "SELECT ORDRE_NR FROM ORDRE_INFO WHERE S_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '? 00:00:00 CET' AND TIMESTAMP '? 00:00:00 CET' or E_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '? 00:00:00 CET' AND TIMESTAMP '? 00:00:00 CET' OR S_DATE <= TIMESTAMP '? 00:00:00 CET' AND E_DATE >= TIMESTAMP '? 00:00:00 CET';";

      PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(query);          

      String S_DATE = s_date;
      String E_DATE = e_date;
      System.out.println("jens");

      prest.setString(1,S_DATE);
      prest.setString(2,E_DATE);
      prest.setString(3,S_DATE);
      prest.setString(4,E_DATE);
      prest.setString(5,S_DATE);      
      prest.setString(6,E_DATE);  

      rs = prest.executeQuery();
```

It crashes and gives me an error "Invalid column Index...."

Anybody got an idea why this fails? I've tried to give it this query instead and it works perfect.

```
String query =  "SELECT ORDRE_NR FROM ORDRE_INFO WHERE 
S_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2007-10-10 00:00:00 CET' 
AND TIMESTAMP '2009-10-10 00:00:00 CET'
or E_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2007-10-10 00:00:00 CET' 
AND TIMESTAMP '2009-10-10 00:00:00 CET'OR S_DATE <= TIMESTAMP '2007-10-10 00:00:00 CET'
AND E_DATE >= TIMESTAMP '2009-10-10 00:00:00 CET'";
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the correct database and schema?

Comment: yup :) the connection is there

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. The ? should not be in quotes. Consider setting

```
 S_DATE=s_date+" 00:00:00 CET"
```

and not in the statement itself.

Then your statement would be :

```
String query = "SELECT ORDRE_NR FROM ORDRE_INFO WHERE S_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP ?  AND TIMESTAMP ? ...."
```

Comment: then I get a missing keyword error... any idea tho this then :)

Comment: Use setTimestamp instead of setString and drop TIMESTAMP from the query

Comment: Thanks :) got a whole new world of problems now but I think that solved some of it :)

Comment: Ok looked at it again... something just dont add up.. there needs to be TIMESTAMP in the query... sql needs to know that its comparing Timestamps else it wont work.. if you look at the second query I've tried with by hard codeing the timestamp into the query earlier you will see this.. I've tried what your suggesting but It still doesnt work.. When I sout the S_DATE string it looks like this 2007-10-10 00:00:00 CET wich I cant see is different from the hardcoding done in the second query above... then it returns invalid collum.. just dont get it